# Adding triangles to a boxplot using R and ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot, annotate

I'm building a simple boxplot (without whiskers) with the R code below. I need to annotate or add triangles to this plot but I'm not sure what the best approach to accomplish this is. Heres an image of what the plot should look like. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, color=factor(cyl)))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0, coef = 0)

p + coord_flip() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#6498AD", "#BA401A", "#b1bd21", "#E9B207")) +  
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
        legend.position="none",
        panel.background=element_blank(), 
        panel.border=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
        plot.background=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: And those triangles are pointing at what?

Comment: that actually a good question, it can be any point thats within a box. @zx8754

Comment: I am curious, what are you really pointing at... What is the point of pointing a triangle at a random point?

Comment: the box would represent a range of coverage I expect while the triangle will be where a sample fell for a particular experiment, so technically the triangle may fall outside of the expected range. the dataset I'm testing with is erroneous. @zx8754

Comment: You can use `geom_point`: just pass the coordinate of where you want the symbol.. `p + geom_point(data=data.frame(y=seq(unique(mtcars$cyl)), x = c(26, 20, 15)),aes(y, x), 
               pch=25 , size=5 , fill="red", inherit.aes = F, 
               position=position_nudge(x=0.5))`

Comment: Can you not code those points differently from others using `factor` and then use `shape` within `geom_point` to change them to triangle?